# How do I give my application the capability to make an AdUser api call

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to programmatically create and manage facebook advertising campaigns.

The following is my python code:

```
my_app_id = 'MyAppId'
my_app_secret = 'MyAppSecret'
my_access_token = 'MyAccessToken'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = AdUser(fbid='MyFbId')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())
print(my_accounts)
```

Sadly, when I run this function I get an error from the following line:

```
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())
```

The error is:

```
facebookads.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/643866195/adaccounts
  Params:  {'summary': 'true'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
        "code": 3, 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "H3BFNpSClup"
      }
    }
```

I have tried messing with a few things to resolve this. One thing I thought would work was to add my account ID to the Authorized Ad Account Ids in the Facebook Develop App settings page but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also stuck at the same error